# Как автоматически создавать субдомены?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, apache2, mod-rewrite

Как настроить Apache2 для субдоменов?

Например:
Если в браузере ввели запрос `www.example.com` или `example.com`, то сервер вернул содержимое каталога `/var/www/example.com/www`. Если запрашивается адрес `subdomain1.example.com`, то сервер должен вернуть `/var/www/example.com/subdomain1`. Соответственно, для `subdomain2.example.com` - `/var/www/example.com/subdomain2` и т.д.
Если же каталога `subdomainN` не существует - вернуть ошибку `404`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

поможет перенапрвление в .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /var/www/example.com/subdomains/$1 [L]
```

думаю Вы это хотели

Answer (score 0):

такое можно осуществить, например, с помощью модуля [vhost_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html).

1. включите модуль. в *debian*-основных дистрибутивах это можно сделать, например, так:

   ```
   $ sudo a2enmod vhost_alias
   ```
2. добавьте в конфигурацию `apache` строку примерно такого вида (в файл `/etc/apache2/apache.conf` или что-то подобное; например, можно даже создать отдельный файл в `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` и затем включить его командой `sudo a2ensite имя-файла`):

   ```
   virtualdocumentroot /var/www/dynamic/%0
   ```
3. проверьте и перезагрузите конфигурацию `apache`:

   ```
   $ sudo apachectl configtest
   $ sudo service apache reload
   ```
4. создайте каталог и, например, `index.html` в нём:

   ```
   $ sudo mkdir -p /var/www/dynamic/subdomain1.example.com
   $ date | sudo tee /var/www/dynamic/subdomain1.example.com/index.html
   ```

теперь при обращении к `http://subdomain1.example.com` будет отображаться содержимое созданного `index.html`.

конечно, при условии, что имя `subdomain1.example.com` будет разрезолвлено в нужный ip-адрес.